# SQL query questing to filter out rows

Tags: sql

Explanation- In column "Raw content" i am having data like -MSH|^~\&|PYXIS|SJO|PHA|SJF1|201707171217||ACK|587044650|P|2.2|0| MSA|AA|587044650|....... Message in each row in b/w MSH data is different and i need to search for all the rows having MSH|* |* |CACPA| in place of SJO as shown in above example.. *(astric) means any value
What SQL query should be any suggestion?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should include the definition of the tables so that we can help with query.

Comment: Cache is the name of database

Comment: Explanation- In column "Raw content" i am having data like -MSH|^~\&|PYXIS|SJO|PHA|SJF1|201707171217||ACK|587044650|P|2.2|0| MSA|AA|587044650|.......       Message in each row in b/w MSH data is different and i need to search for all the rows having MSH|* |* |CACPA| in place of SJO as shown in above example.. *-> any value

Answer (score 2):

Fix your data structure!  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column.  Instead, you should have a separate table with one row per whatever and per color.  That is the *right* way to use a relational database.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  There is a way around this:

```
where concat('|', colors, '|') not like '%|Red|%'
```

Comment: Explanation- In column "Raw content" i am having data like -MSH|^~\&|PYXIS|SJO|PHA|SJF1|201707171217||ACK|587044650|P|2.2|0| MSA|AA|587044650|.......       Message in each row in b/w MSH data is different and i need to search for all the rows having MSH|* |* |CACPA| in place of SJO as shown in above example.. *-> any value

Comment: I suggest you try and understand the answer rather than repeatedly pasting in an unclear explanation. What makes you think it makes any more sense the third time around?